# How to Get the ids of span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of the span tags like .

```
 <span id="q_1" >D1</span>
 <span id="q_2" >D2</span>
 <span id="q_3" >D3</span>
```

How can i get the ids of the span tags with the help of the jquery.The numbers 1,2,3 are generated run time.so the basic structure that i have is

```
<span id="q_" ></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you're actually asking how to select all elements that have an id that starts with "q_".  If so, the simplest way to do so is like this:

```
var qSpans = $('span[id^="q_"]');
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/u4MnZ/)

Comment: Many questions on stackoverflow seem to involve pressing keys randomly until satisfied :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$("span").each(function(){
     var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
     // Do whatever you want with the Id, and go on to the next one.
});
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('span').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

to get an array if ids:

```
var a = $.map($('span'), function(s){ return s.id; });
```

Comment: var a = $.map($('span[id^="q_"]'), function(s){ return s.attr('id'); });

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span');
```

Will find all spans.

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return (/^q\_\d+$/i).test($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Or only spans who's id matches the format